# How to edit WordPress CSS written as inline CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, inline

I'm trying to edit the CSS of a WordPress template.

I am using Firefox to find the CSS styles and found the line I need to edit, which looks like this:

```
<div style="transition: height 350ms ease 0s; height: 450px;" class="og-expander">
```

What I want to do is to change `height: 450px` to `height: 100%`.

I have tried editing the `og-expander` class' height, but it didn't work.
I realized that the `height` property within `og-expander` are disabled because of the inline CSS, but I can't find the place to edit the inline CSS.

I have searched through some other CSS files as well, but I failed to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the style added directly to the element with !important after the style statement in your css files. For instance

```
.og-expander {
    height: 350px !important;
    transition: 0 !important;
}
```

Also, you might try searching all your php files to edit that place directly. If its added in core or plugins, direct editing would be a bad idea, so try to find an appropriate filter or action hook.